# php - identifying location of pattern in graphic

Tags: php, image, image-processing, pattern-matching

I'm doing a little research to see if it is possible to write php that is able to process an image by identifying the location of a particular pattern/object, and then output the x-y pixel location of the object.

The project is to be used to process maps of a, where all the maps are generated using the same process and the icon for a seat remains the same (including the same size - 16x17 pixels) in each case.

A typical map would look like http://s140173.gridserver.com/so/map.gif

...and so obviously, the individual icon looks like http://s140173.gridserver.com/so/icon.gif

I was planning to loop a 'search' script of some kind to find the first 'icon', add the x-y location of the icon to an array, then black out/distort the icon (in memory using an image function) and repeat the search to again find 'the first icon' (as the original would no longer match as it's been distorted) - but am unsure of any class/function/extension that has the ability to match graphics in this way.

Any thoughts on how this pattern matching might be accomplished? Are there any libraries or extensions out there that are capable of doing this? If not, can anyone suggest another platform that may be appropriate?

Cheers.

Comment: I didn't read the whole thing, but this page, or others like it, might be helpful: http://www.searchlores.org/finn_cbir_2.htm

Comment: php does have some functions you could work with, like [imagecolorclosest](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorclosest.php), [imagecolorat](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) and lots of others. I don't think it's impossible what you want!

Comment: XOR'ing might be helpful, imagick is able to do that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.composite.php - but PHP won't be the fastest language to process all possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Using GD this would be VERY slow and inefficient, but assuming the icon is going to be the same size, you could loop through the image easily and keep comparing every possible rectangle of that size until you find a match. That would just be two `for` loops, getting the color with `imagecolorat`, and comparing these rectangles to your target, for which there are numerous easy ways to implement. But I don't recommend this, as it will take seconds to locate each little target.

You might want to look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com) which can do this type of intelligent analysis on images, but it is quite complicated to use. This would be the better way of doing it, but it is not PHP and might be overkill for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks, Alasdair. OpenCV looks a little over the top for what we need, but definitely an interesting tool. I've come up with a solution based on using imagecolorat and simply tagging each icon with an off-white 1x1 pixel at the 0,0 position. The script loops through map, checking each pixel, and if it matches the correct color index, it adds the x,y values to an array. Much easier that trying to recognize images. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds like a fine solution, though if you are in control of the generated images anyway... why not just records the coordinates in the first place?

Comment: The maps are generated by our marketing team - normally using Photoshop and stuff like that. So we don't have a _lot_ of control over the generation - but they have previously used template icons, and so I've just updated the template icons they use to include this 1x1 marker pixel.